# How to adapt the size of a WPF Page automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my C#.NET WPF application, I make use of a WPF window to display multiple WPF pages (one at the time) depending on the context and data. One WPF Page is used to display categories of products, and another WPF Page is used to display products of a certain category.

To do so, I defined within a grid, in the WPF Window, a mainframe as follows (this is the grid used to show the Page):

```
<Grid x:Name="gridPage" Grid.Row="1">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">-
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrame"></Frame>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Changing a WPF Page is as simple as setting the content of the mainframe equals to the WPF Page I want to display:

```
//In the code-behind
mainFrame.Content = someWPFPage;
```

When I create a WPF Page destined to display categories, I set the width and height of the WPF page equals to the ActualWidht and ActualHeight of the gridPage Grid (shown in the first code snippet), which means that the page fits exactly in the mainframe, since they both have the same width and height.

The issue is that whenever I'm adding categories withing that WPF Page, certain categories are not shown, maybe because of the fact that the dimensions of the page are fixed. I thought that adding a scrollbar to the mainFrame would fix the issue, but it's not the case.

```
----------------------------------
|          |          |          |
|   Cat1   |   Cat2   |   Cat3   |
|          |          |          |
----------------------------------
|          |          |          |
|   Cat4   |   Cat5   |   Cat6   |
|          |          |          |
----------------------------------
|          |          |          |
|   Cat7   |   Cat8   |   Cat9   |
|          |          |          |
----------------------------------
```

Like visualized in the example right above, the last row of categories is not shown because it maybe falls out of the scope of the defined height and width of the WPF Page. Is there any way to solve this problem? By making the height of the page more flexible, but yet still fitting in the mainframe?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by doing the following: `gridOfPageX.Height = double.NaN`. I'm now able to add a lot of categories and to use the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, instead of specifying an explicit width or height for a WPF control you could set its HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Stretch (or don't set them at all since these are the default values) to make it stretch to fill the entire available space.

Setting the Height property to `double.NaN` does effectively remove the specific height constraint on the element which will make it stretch vertically unless you have set the VerticalAlignment property to something else than Stretch.